# Selenium web driver python unable to locate element by id

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I'm attempting to get Selenium webdriver to select an option from a dropdown menu from the page referenced below.

The drop down menu looks like this:

```
<select name="_year" id="select1" onchange="this.form.submit();" style="width: 10%; font: 12px Arial;">
<option selected="">All Years
</option><option>2018-19
</option><option>2017-18
</option><option>2016-17
</option><option>2015-16
</option><option>2014-15
</option><option>2013-14
</option><option>2012-13
</option><option>2011-12
</option><option>2010-11
</option><option>2009-10
</option><option>2008-09
</option><option>2007-08
</option><option>2006-07
</option><option>2005-06
</option><option>2004-05
</option><option>2003-04
</option><option>2002-03
</option><option>2001-02
</option></select>
```

I'm trying to select the 2018-19 option from the dropdown:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:/Users/path/to/chromedriver.exe")
site = "http://edsight.ct.gov/SASStoredProcess/do?_program=%2FCTDOE%2FEdSight%2FRelease%2FReporting%2FPublic%2FReports%2FStoredProcesses%2FProfilePerformanceReport&_default=Yes&_select=Submit"
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get(site)

# ------------ getting to subpage ----------- #
year = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("select1"))
year.select_by_visible_text("2018-19")
```

However, when I run, I get the following error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="select1"]"}
  (Session info: chrome=87.0.4280.141)
```

Any thoughts on how to reference the element and select?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to search element by Xpath instead of id. It'll give you better results.

- To select from the drop down using Xpath, it should look like this or maybe different for you:

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='id'].../div[n]/.../select/option[1]").click()
  ```

#### or

- To select from the drop down using arrows:

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
  from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

  step_1 = ActionChains(driver)
  step_1.send_keys(Keys.DOWN, Keys.RETURN)
  ```

#### or

- you can use this method:

  ```
  year.select_by_value('1')
  ```

Hope it helps, if issues please comment.